# Terminology: "registers" in assembly language programming

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

I've heard the terminologies: register, hardware register, program register,register file.

What's the difference between all these? And in assebmly, what is the type of the EAX register? Program register?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A register is a storage area inside the CPU. Here are some definitions:

- A register file is an array of registers - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_file for a full description.
- The eax register is the accumulator register of the Intel x86 family of CPUs - it's the place where integer maths gets done.
- The program register (I think you mean program counter) is a special purpose register which contains the address of the next machine code instruction to be executed

Comment: In 8086 and later, and definitely in 32bit (386) and modern x86-64, all the registers are essentially general-purpose.  Many also have special purposes (like shift counts in `ecx`, and full-multiply (32bx32b => 64b) still requires one input in `eax`), but `add eax, edx` and `add esp, ebp` are just two different choices of src/dest for the `add` instruction.  32bit x86 basically has 7 general purpose registers.  Using `esp` as anything other than the stack pointer is not usually possible / worth it in real code.

Comment: "program registers" could mean the register part of the [architectural state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_state) of a process.  When you're talking about context-switching between threads, or if you're in kernel code, then the "program registers" might be the user-space state you saved on entry into the kernel.  It's not just a weird name for "program counter" or "instruction pointer".

Answer (score 6):

A register is the most basic data storage device. Now these are the main differences.

A register file is generally a large collection of registers organised in such a way so that they are used for computations. In a modern processor, all computations are performed between values stored in several registers in a register file.

A hardware register generally refers to registers that store configuration and status information. This could be for the processor or some external hardware I/O device.

A programme register may refer to the programme counter, a special register that stores the memory location of the current instruction being executed by the processor.

Answer (score 5):

a register is a small bit of memory that sits inside the CPU. and is used by assembly language to perform various tasks.

could it be that by program register you mean program counter?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you have general purpose registers, then you have registers which have special usage (for example, the program counter registers), and you have various others (memory/segment registers, SSE).

EAX, EBX, etc. are the standard general purpose registers. You can use them for whatever you want. Usually, the return value is supposed to be put into EAX, but that's it basically. Then you have the stack pointer EBP, which points to the beginning of your stack. Finally, you have to program counter, which points to the current instruction, EIP. On x86, there are some special cases, where two registers get fused when doing 64-bit integer computations. More special cases exist for the string instructions. If you are about to learn assembly, the easiest would be to start with a PowerPC, which has more registers, and you're free to use all of them without restrictions.

All of these registers are of course hardware registers, that is, they are physically built into your CPU ;) The place where they are is called a register file.

The other type of registers you can see is if you have a virtual machine which uses registers ([Parrot](http://www.parrot.org/)), you get "virtual registers", which are later assigned to real registers. This is similar to what you can do when writing a compiler yourself, you basically assume an unlimited amount of registers (that is, you generate a new one on each usage), and do the transformation to real registers in a different phase (register allocation).

Answer (score 4):

A "hardware register" might also refer to a location inside some hardware device. For example, a UART (COM port) looks like a D-shaped connector with 9 or 25 pins from outside the cabinet, but to the device driver it looks like several configuration registers, a status register, and data registers holding the next character to send and the last character received. (I've left out a *lot* of detail there.)

In the x86 architecture those registers are usually located in a special physical address space that is accessed with I/O instructions. In other platforms, it is common for hardware registers to be mapped to some corner of the normal memory space. In either case, one of the important roles of an operating system and its device drivers is to prevent application code from needing to know the details of where the hardware registers are located and what they mean.

In some kinds of hardware devices, the distinction between memory and hardware registers is less clear. For instance, your video adapter contains a block of memory known as the frame buffer that holds the color and brightness values for each individual pixel. Is that memory a large hardware register or is it just a buffer that has an interesting side effect?

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the question, there are two general types of registers that you should consider:

- program registers
- hardware registers

The hardware registers are clocked (updated on clock ticks) and are used in the **physical** design of processor circuitry.

The program registers are random-access memory and are held in a register file located in the CPU. Assembly/machine code instructions access these registers through names like %eax, %esp, %rdi, %edi, etc.

Comment: "hardware register" in most contexts still means architectural register (`%eax`) or physical registers (that architectural registers are renamed onto).  You are correct that "register" is another term for "latch".  In a ["registered ECC DIMM"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory), the term "registered" means there is a latch between the DRAM chips and the memory bus to give better signal strength when many DIMMs are on the same channel.